# How can I add a loader page to my Gatsby.js site?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, spinner, loader

I created a portfolio website using gatsby and react.js but when someone tries to view it for the first time, it lags on certain css transitions and images causing it to look weird. Afterwards, when you refresh it or go through the pages, it looks fine. I want to add a loader page for a few seconds so that everything loads before going into my main page. I've seen a couple of blogs talking about how to do this but I can't find a solution that is easy to understand. Can someone help? I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `gatsby-plugin-nprogress` plugin, which adds a thin progress bar at the top of your site while the page is loading. You can customize the color, speed, and position of the progress bar. You can install the plugin with `npm install gatsby-plugin-nprogress` and add it to your `gatsby-config.js` file with some options.

For example:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-nprogress`,
      options: {
        color: `tomato`,
        showSpinner: false,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```